# pipenv shell fails to create a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pipenv

`pipenv shell` command fails in creating a virtual environment. I tried re-installing pipenv but that doesn't works for me.

```
C:\Users\Shubh\Desktop\projects\pystart>pipenv lock
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\Shubh\Desktop\projects\pystart\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/Shubh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe (3.8.3) to create virtualenv...
[   =] Creating virtual environment...RuntimeError: failed to build image setuptools, wheel because:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 55, in _install
    if not installer.has_image():
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 143, in has_image
    return self._image_dir.exists() and next(self._image_dir.iterdir()) is not None
StopIteration

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\via_app_data.py", line 57, in _install
    installer.install(creator.interpreter.version_info)
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 46, in install
    for name, module in self._console_scripts.items():
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 116, in _console_scripts
    entry_points = self._dist_info / "entry_points.txt"
  File "c:\users\shubh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\embed\via_app_data\pip_install\base.py", line 103, in _dist_info
    raise RuntimeError(msg)  # pragma: no cover
RuntimeError: no .dist-info at C:\Users\Shubh\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any, has wheel


Failed creating virtual environment

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Can anyone help me solve me this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting these two folders and then running `pipenv shell` fixed it for me.

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any

C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\wheel\3.8\image\1\CopyPipInstall\setuptools-51.0.0-py3-none-any
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help in your situation as my screen reader was not reading the entire message, but I simply imported a new profile and it sorted the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have both python 3.11 and python 3.10, when I tried to install pipenv using pip for 3.10, pip is using cached version of setuptools and wheel that was downloaded when I installed pipenv for 3.11.

Updating setuptools and wheel resolved this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use virtualenv instead of pipenv to create virtual environment.

check below link to install and  know use of virtualenv:-

https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-install-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-18-04-2jdi

After installing virtualenv you can create env like this:-

`virtualenv your_env_name -p python3  # use for python3` and you can also write specific version of python3 like python3.5 or python3.7

`virtualenv your_env_name -p python2` # use for python2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want to know why this is not working, because previously I was using pipenv for creating virtual environments and it worked fine, but now its not working.

Comment: I tried with virtualenv still I am getting the same error.